# SQL replace query

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, substring

Maybe It is very simple for a person who are using database every day, but
I need to write sql query. I've got fields (85500 items) which are in the 
same design for example '200 00 2334', '200 00 2555' (it's varchar data),
it's a code of customers. I need to change all of this fields to for example
'200-00 2334', '200-00 2555'. The first space in the field must be replaced into '-'
the second space must stay without changes. 
My database is a PostgreSQL. I need only a query.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2):

As chance would have it regexp_replace() will do the job with a trivial pattern-match since it will only match the first space.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('100 200 300', ' ', '-');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 100-200 300
```

Comment: that's what I want. I've used the query: update konta_wirtualne set kw_kod_kontrahenta = regexp_replace(kw_kod_kontrahenta, ' ', '-')

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's always the 4th character, you can use [overlay](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html):

```
select overlay('200 00 12132' placing '-' from 4 for 1);
--------------------------------------------------------
OVERLAY
200-00 12132
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select code[1]||'-'||code[2]||' '||code[3] from
 (select regexp_split_to_array('200 00 2334', E'\\s+') as code) t
```

This keeps you more flexible if the first part of the code has different amount of charaters